# Meaning of "water, the weight of which is one-eighth hydrogen"

Tags: meaning, sentence-meaning

I have a question about the article written by Isaac Asimov in 1987 that was published in the Los Angeles Times. It said

> For instance, coal, oil, and gas all contain hydrogen atoms and you can obtain pure hydrogen from them, but it takes some energy to do this. You have to burn some oil to get hydrogen out of other oil and in this way, you end up with less fuel than you started with.
>
> Is there anything that contains hydrogen that is not a fuel? **Yes-there is water, the weight of which is one-eighth hydrogen**. The only trouble is that ripping the hydrogen out of water takes energy.

(title: Quest for Fuel an Ongoing Objective, LA times (1987)),

Should I interpret this as meaning 'Yes-there is water, the weight of which is one-eighth of hydrogen'?

When you say that A is one-eighth of B, that means A=1/8×B, right? However, does this mean that water is lighter than hydrogen? Even though water is actually heavier than hydrogen.

Comment: Welcome to ELL, sukekiyo. Please edit your question to add a link to the article. If that is not available, please add the complete paragraph containing the sentence that you quoted, and also some information about the subject of the article.  As it stands, it is impossible to answer your question without any context because, as you say, it doesn't seem to fit the facts. With some context, we may be able to work out how the confusion has arisen.

Comment: Water by mass is 8/9 oxygen and 1/9 hydrogen. The mass ratio is 8 oxygen to 1 hydrogen. This must surely be what Asimov was saying. The mass of hydrogen in a given amount of water is one eighth the mass of oxygen.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey I agree, but possibly Azimov could have phrased it better (and more accurately), something like "Hydrogen comprises 1/9 of the weight water"

Comment: sukekiyo - I don't understand the point of your edit. The original question was meaningful precisely *because* the typo caused the text to apparently be making an absurdly inaccurate claim. The difference between 1/8th and 1/9th is insignificant here, but that unwanted ***of*** makes it the difference between ***one eighth*** and ***eight times***, which is clearly significant.

Comment: @Fumblefingers　Even without the word "of," I had thought that "there is water, the weight of which is one-eighth hydrogen" had the same meaning as "the weight of water is one-eighth of hydrogen." In fact, when I entered "there is water, the weight of which is one-eighth hydrogen" into a translation site, one of the candidates for the Japanese interpretation was "the weight of water is one-eighth of hydrogen."

Comment: @Fumblefingers　Thanks to you, I learned for the first time that the presence or absence of "of" makes a big difference in whether it is "eight times" or "one-eighth." Could you please give me some examples of this type of sentence?

I know that "one-ninth" is more appropriate than "one-eighth," but that wasn't what I was questioning, so I didn't mention it.

Comment: Not what you are asking about, but note that _**the** article by Isaac Asimov_  is confusing, because it implies "I expect you to know which article I mean". _An article by Isaac Asimov_ would be more normal.

Comment: sukekiyo - does it help if I point out that the second ***of*** in *the weight of water is 1/8th **of** hydrogen* is "reduced" from *...is 1/8th **of the weight of** hydrogen* (i.e. - water only weighs an eighth as much as hydrogen, which is obviously nonsense even though it's syntactically valid). But when ***of*** is *not* present, the text is "reduced" from *...is 1/8th **comprised of** hydrogen* (i.e. - the hydrogen in water only accounts for 1/8th of the water's total weight, which is close enough! :)

Comment: For a given amount of water, hydrogen accounts for one-eighth of its weight.

Answer (score 29):

The text is mistranscribed. [The original says...](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22Yes-there%20is%20water%2C%20the%20weight%20of%20which%20is%20one-eighth%20of%20hydrogen%22)

> Q: *Is there anything that contains hydrogen that is not a fuel?*
> A: *Yes, there is water, **the weight of which is one - eighth hydrogen***

Crucially, there's no ***of*** before ***hydrogen*** (or possessive ***'s*** *after* it).

Asimov isn't saying that water weighs only an eighth as much as hydrogen - he's saying that one eighth of the weight of water comes from the hydrogen it contains - along with oxygen, one atom of which which is 16 times heavier than a hydrogen atom (but water is H**2**O, and 16/2=**8**).

---

EDIT: It's fully covered in comments, but in fact Asimov should have said that for any given weight of water, **1/9th** comes from the hydrogen it contains (16 from one atom of oxygen plus 2 atoms of hydrogen gives **18**, so hydrogen's contribution to "total weight" = 2/18 = **1/9**). But this doesn't affect the syntax.

Comment: Only one-**ninth** of the 'weight of water' comes from hydrogen. Hydrogen atomic weight = 1. Oxygen atomic weight = 16. A molecule of water is 2 atoms of H and one atom of O. 16+1+1=18. In a given weight of water, the ratio of weight of water to hydrogen is 9:1, and of oxygen to hydrogen is 8:1. These are rounded figures.

Comment: That's all "external" knowledge about chemistry and arithmetic (I knew *someone* would pick me up re "inaccuracy" in my final bracketed observation! :)   But sticking to the relevant aspects of ***language***, it's just a matter of an extraneous ***of*** creeping in.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I apologize for the typing error.
May I ask a question?
Does "one-eighth" modify "hydrogen" or "the weight of water"? If it modifies "the weight of water", could you please explain the grammar behind why it does so? If a native speaker sees "Yes-there is water, the weight of which is one-eighth hydrogen," would they be able to interpret it as "one eighth of the weight of water comes from the hydrogen it contains" even without any knowledge of chemistry?

Comment: Yes - *once the transcription error is fixed,* you don't need anything except basic English syntax to understand the cited text. Note that Asimov could just as well have said *There is water, one-eighth of the weight of which is hydrogen*. Which is just another way of saying *One eighth of the weight of water is* [or *comes from*] [the] hydrogen [it contains].*

Comment: @FumbleFingers - if he did, he would be wrong, because  there is water, **one-ninth** of the weight of which is hydrogen.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: So you keep saying. But one eighth was good enough for Asimov to make his point, and it's *certainly* good enough for learners who want to understand the syntax.

Comment: ...of course, there's not that much "pure" H2O around anyway. Deuterium (and more so Tritium) might not exist in vast quantities, but I assume they're *everywhere* (like the oft-cited water from Jesus' blood or urine, tiny amounts of which apparently exist in *all* our bodies! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers - I wonder if homeopaths consider the pee of Jesus?

Comment: Maybe it's a foible of mine, but I am unhappy with numerical inaccuracy about simple things. If my grandfather left me one-eighth of his million-pound estate, and the executor decided to give me one-ninth instead, and said 'that's near enough', I'd be holding my hand out for the missing £13,888.89. I could get a nice little car with that. Asimov was a respected author of chemistry text books and a professor of biochemistry, so he's have known the right figures.

Comment: In his essay "To Tell a Chemist" (1965), Asimov proposed a simple shibboleth for distinguishing chemists from non-chemists: ask the person to read the word "unionized". Chemists, he noted, will read un-ionized (electrically neutral), while non-chemists will read union-ized (belonging to a trade union).

Comment: @MichaelHarvey That's a good one! I've always been a great admirer of Asimov. Especially since I can respect him as a *person* as well as a good sci-fi and popular science writer. Unlike Arthur C Clarke, now known to be a pedophile as well as a not-as-good-as-Asimov sci-fi writer. Or L Ron Hubbard - now known to be a Scientology nutter as well as a not-even-as-good-as-*Clarke* sci-fi writer.

Comment: I have been happily revisiting a favourite of my youth, James Blish. Clarke couldn't do characters, especially women, a failing, in my opinion, shared by Gregory Benford. Don't get me started on Heinlein.

Comment: I've fixed the quote in the question I hope I@ve done so in such a way that does not invalidate this answer.

Comment: @JamesK: Nicely done! ty

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: I can't resist pointing out that homeopaths may consider that the pees of Jesus passeth all understanding! But seriously - we'd better close off this comment thread before we get our knuckles rapped!

Comment: @sukekiyo "could you please explain the grammar behind why it does so?" The word "of" is required when you want water to weigh 1/8th **of** the weight of water.  In he case of Asimov's article, water is by weight 1/8th hydrogen.  He definitely could have worded it better.

Comment: @sukekiyo I actually think even native speakers would have trouble with this _if they had no knowledge of chemistry_ because it's not really obvious that there is hydrogen in water if you don't know any chemistry. But native speakers would have no problem with "there is my luggage, the weight of which is one-eighth books"...meaning that you've packed a lot of books in your luggage.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I'm not an Arthur C. Clarke expert, but the Wikipedia page for him seems to say that that accusation was retracted by the newspaper that originally reported it, and the paper published an apology (along with references).

Comment: @user3067860 I’m not so sure about that. Even with the extraneous _of_ gone, I can’t fully wrap my brain around the phrasing “the weight… is 1/8 hydrogen”. It’s an extremely odd way to word it to me, one that makes no logical sense at all. Removing the fraction, you’re saying (well, Asimov is) that _the weight is hydrogen_, which it isn’t. Weight is not hydrogen, and hydrogen is not weight – they’re orthogonal notions. It’s somehow understandable, but the more I think about it, the less sense it makes. It really needs a preposition ‘from’ to make proper sense.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet "the <quantitative property> of which is <fraction> <component>" is a grammatical construction that means the fraction is as measured by the given property. It is equivalent to "<fraction> of which, *as measured by <quantitative property>*, is <component>". Applying this to the specific quote in question, it means "1/8th of which, as measured by weight, is hydrogen." This grammatical construction would never be used without the fraction, precisely because removing the fraction renders it nonsensical. It is used to emphasize the specified quantitative property.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Would you feel the same if instead of 1/8 you had the word "half"? Perhaps a drink is half gin, half juice. I suppose we're more used to measuring those things by volume rather than weight/mass, maybe a dough of half flour half water?

Comment: @Douglas It’s definitely grammatical, no doubt about that. I never said it wasn’t. But it does mess with my mind in a way that applying the fraction to _weight_ instead of _hydrogen_ doesn’t. “1/8 of the weight of water is [from] hydrogen” is logically parseable to me (even without the preposition, though still better with it); “the weight of water is 1/8 [from] hydrogen” is not, at least not without the preposition. It somehow remains more or less understandable, even while breaking my brain logically, but it’s not natural at all.

Comment: @BryanKrause No, _half_ doesn’t make it better. I think it’s because when you start out specifying the weight, you’re no longer measuring the components of the object itself (water), but of its weight specifically. Gin and juice are components of the drink, not of its weight. Half the weight can _come from_ gin/juice, but half the weight cannot _be_ gin/juice. Similarly, I have no problem with “water, which is two thirds hydrogen” (ignoring chemical accuracy), since hydrogen is a component of water; but hydrogen is not a component of the _weight_ of water.

Comment: It becomes even clearer if we swap weight for a different property; for example, “the Empire State Building, the height of which is two thirds concrete”. That is a parallel, and still grammatical, statement that logically breaks down because concrete is not a component of the height of a building. Here the breakdown is clearer, because concrete is not something we think of as having a ‘height’ property in itself (whereas anything inherently has a ‘weight’ property), but the concept is the same.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - I have no trouble whatsoever with something like 'My patent concrete is made of various things, but one-quarter the weight is limestone. Luckily I own a quarry'.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Expanding slightly to “one quarter _of_ the weight”, I have at least _less_ trouble with that than with “but the weight is one quarter limestone” (‘one quarter the weight’ is not grammatical in my English, though it sounds like something that may be fine within a particular field). But I would still find it more natural and logical to say “but it is one quarter limestone by weight” or “but limestone accounts for/makes up a quarter of the weight”.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - I think that 'naturalness' and 'logicality' are in (or behind) the eye of the reader, and furthermore that the second of these is a pitfall for learners of English, which is, supremely, not 'logical'.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet "She's really tall!" "Yes, but like 6 inches of that is her heels and another 6 inches is just hair." In this case, if you took away the heels and hair, the person would be shorter. So if you told me that 2/3rd of the height of the ESB is concrete, then I would expect that it was on some gigantic concrete plinth or something so that the concrete would relate specifically to the height. (Another example would be a balloon or sponge that might be really big but "the volume is mostly air".)

Comment: @user3067860 Note that you also automatically switched to the (to me) more acceptable version here, stating that ‘[X part] of the height is [Y]’, rather than ‘the height is [X part] [Y]’. ‘6 inches of her height is her heels’ is fairly normal to me, whereas ‘Her height is 6 inches her heels’ is very odd.

Comment: @Beska: The precise definition of "pedophile" will vary from person to person. I don't know how old Clarke's *youngest* sexual partner was in later life, but I'm pretty sure he was picking up "boys" aged under 18 when he was well into his 70s.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - considering that he was part of my GCE 'O' level English course, and that _Dulce et Decorum est_ was read by the head boy on my school's service on the battle the Somme's 50th anniversary, about Wilfred Owen, I was taken aback by the allegations, and, just now, again, to discover that he was pleased, in 1914, to feel '[his] own life all the more precious and more dear in the presence of this deflowering of Europe', during which 'the guns will effect a little useful weeding'. Deflowering! So much to unpack there. I accept that he was 21, and many 21 year olds are fools.

Answer (score 9):

It means that if you have *x* weight of water, then x/8 of that is hydrogen.

---

As you know, water is H<sub>2</sub>O — two hydrogen atoms for one oxygen atoms.  Hydrogen's atomic weight is 1.008, while oxygen's is 15.999.  So the total molecular weight of water is 1.008×2+15.999 = 18.015, and the composition of water by mass is:

- Hydrogen: (1.008×2)/18.015 ≈ 11.19% ≈ 1/9
- Oxygen: 15.999/18.015 ≈ 88.81% ≈ 8/9

So Asimov made an arithmetic error, apparently using 16 (the weight of oxygen) in the denominator instead of 18 (the total weight of the molecule).  He meant to say “Yes-there is water, the weight of which is one-**ninth** hydrogen.”

Comment: You don't often throw your hat in the ring here on ELU - but when you do, it's usually solid stuff! I knew there was *something* not quite right about the arithmetic here (*and* I suspected the initial numbers weren't actually integers anyway), but you've definitely nailed the "numbers game" for me with this answer! The *actual* question turns on the significance of ***of*** in the cited text, which only really involves hypothetical confusion as to whether the underlying assertion is *Water weighs 1/8th as much as hydrogen* or *1/8th of water's weight comes from the hydrogen it contains...*

Comment: ...I'm content that I've covered the actual *language* issueds in my answer, but I like that there's a concise summary here of the exact measurable numbers and relevant arithmetic operations, for anyone who wants to dig that deep!

Comment: @FumbleFingers, well, it's mostly just the number of protons and neutrons anyway, so integers to a great extent.

Comment: @ilkkachu: I already a vague feeling that it's "integers to a great extent", rather than ***always exactly integers*** (which as ChatGTP has just informed me, is because of isotopes). And really that's why I expected at least *someone* to challenge the final assertion in my own answer. But I figured that was complicated stuff that many people wouldn't know anyway. On the other hand, I'm a bit shamefaced at having to admit that I didn't register the "1/8th or 1/9th" issue until it was pointed out to me (my only consolation being that Asimov himself seems to have made the same mistake).

Comment: @FumbleFingers: And even pure isotopes (except carbon-12) don't have exact integer atomic masses [because there is a miniscule mass difference between protons and neutrons](https://education.jlab.org/qa/particlemass_02.html).

Comment: @dan04: Oh Lord! And there was me thinking I [almost] understood what was going on, once I grasped the isotopes business! But the truth is it's *way* past my pay grade!

Comment: It's not just because of different isotopes, and the mass difference between protons and neutrons.  There's also the nuclear binding energy, which makes the mass of a nucleus slightly less than the total of the masses of protons and neutrons in it.

Answer (score 1):

Adding because I don't see any answer saying this explicitly.

The word "one-eighth" in the sentence is acting as an adverb to "is" as opposed to the apparent assumption that it is acting as an adjective to "hydrogen".

So, think of it as:

> The weight of water is mostly oxygen.

But, you replace "mostly" with "one-eighth" and oxygen with hydrogen.

So, the "one-eighth" describes the verb "is." It tells you that instead of you meaning "is fully," you mean only "is one-eighth."

Comment: This is the clearest substitute of all the answers. This helped me understood the syntax. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think there is too much emphasis here on whether 1/8 or 1/9 is more correct; this is language, not science. The point is to understand his meaning; that a small fraction of water is composed of Hydrogen, but it's rather hard to get at, essentially not worth the effort.

I'm not sure how hydrogen cell batteries would fit into his discussion, but they essentially do the reverse: take oxygen and hydrogen, and combine them to produce water, electricity, and a bit of heat.

I'll throw in a little story, as a life-long (more or less) fan of Mr. Asimov:
One morning circa 1992, I awoke with the oddest thought: "I wonder how Isaac Asimov is doing?" (Certainly nothing I had ever pondered before.)
Within minutes, my clock-radio went off, and the two rock djs announced that he had passed away. (How these two djs even knew his name, I haven't a clue.)